# How to initialize a String array with unknown length to null?

Tags: java, arrays, string, prolog, initialization

I'mm working on this program in which connects Prolog and Java GUI. And i am encountering this problem where i don't know how many solutions the prolog program is gonna pass to java and therefore i can't declare the String array with fixed-length. This is my code:

```
String[] options; int i;
Query qMeat = new Query(new Compound("meat", new Term[] {new Variable("X")}));
i = 0;

while(qMeat.hasMoreSolution()){
   options[i] = "" + qMeat.nextSolution().get("X");
   i++;
}
```

I am getting this NullPointerException, which i guess because i didn't initialize the String array to null. And i don't know how to do so. I tried `java.util.Arrays.fill(options,"")` But not helping =(

Please help.

Comment: You're asking "How do I create an array in Java?"? (Declaring a variable which holds a reference to an array is not the same as creating an array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

Comment: Umm... sorry. I mean.. how can i initialize the String array with unknown length to null.. since i m getting this NullPointerException for not initializing it. Is there a way? (I'm sorry that my English is poor.)

Comment: @Ye'ThuraAg There is no way. You have to use `ArrayList` like @Eran suggested below

Comment: @Ye'ThuraAg It already *is* initialized to null, that's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the required size of the array in advance, you should use an ArrayList instead.

```
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
while(qMeat.hasMoreSolution()){
   options.add("" + qMeat.nextSolution().get("X"));
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. Thank you so much ^_^ Haven't tried that yet.